# Do not print unmatched text with sed

Tags: linux, sed

I want to print only matched lines and strip unmatched ones, but with following:

```
$ echo test12 test  | sed -n 's/^.*12/**/p'
```

I always get:

```
** test
```

instead of:

```
**
```

What am I doing wrong?

[edit1]

I provide more information of what I need - and actually I should start with it. So, I have a command which produced lots of lines of output, I want to grab only parts of the lines - the ones that matches, and strip the result. So in the above example 12 was meant to find end of matched part of the line, and instead of ** I should have put & which represents matched string. So the full example is:

```
echo test12 test  | sed -n 's/^.*12/&/p'
```

which produces exactly the same output as input:

```
test12 test
```

the expected output is:

```
test12
```

As suggested I started to find a grep alternative and the following looks promising:

```
$ echo test12 test  | grep -Eo "^.*12"
```

but I dont see how to format the matched part, this only strips unmatched text.

Comment: For me is not very clear what you want, but maybe is this: `echo test12 test  | sed -n 's/^.*12.*/**/p'`.

Comment: If the output of `echo` doesn't look like your input file, post your input file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** In some cases, the -E flag might be needed for sed. But then the brackets don't need to be escaped anymore. check your sed's man page.

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
echo test12 test  | sed -n 's/^\(.*12\).*$/\1/p'
```

if you want to discard the rest of the line, you have to match it as well, but not include it in the output. the `\(` and `\)` denote a group that is then referenced by the `\1`.

Good luck :)

Additional information on sed: 
sed works on lines, and the ampersand characters represents the entire line that was matched by the given regular expression. if a regex is "open" at the end (i.e. doesn't end with the endline character (`$`), it acts as if `.*$` is appended to the match string. (not sure if that is how it is implemented, but could very well be.)

Comment: Thank you! - I want to add that \1 requires -E switch

Comment: really? Interesting, it doesn't for me :). Good to know, let me amend the answer then.

Comment: I am running it on macos and `$ echo test12 test  | sed -n 's/^(.*12).*/\1/p'` gives: `sed: 1: "s/^(.*12).*/\1/p": \1 not defined in the RE`

Comment: Yeah, you can leave -E off, and then you have to escape the brackets.
EDIT: Like i did in the example ;)

EDIT2: my first accepted answer! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo test12 test  | sed -n 's/^.*/**/p'
```

You don't need to match the number 12, since that is already being done in your regex.

Comment: Sorry, I should have prepared better question - I want to use this command to extract first part of the results of some other command (which is multiline). Initially sed looked like that: sed -n 's/^.*12/&/p', so 12 was to find some part of line where match should end, and matched part was being outputed with &, but for some reasons sed always outputs also all unmatched part

Comment: @mike You are right. Please provide valid input, coding effort and desired output. Just copy&paste it from your command line.

Comment: @JohnGoofy I have added more information as Edit to my question

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is matching anything from the beginning of the line until the expression '12'. All the matched expression is replaced with '**', that is why you get '** test'. If you want only match I recommend you using grep.